# Parsing HTML with hpple

Tags: iphone, parsing, hpple

I have some experience with parsing a simple HTML but not a large ones. I am making an iphone app with multiple `tableView` that use *hpple* to parse HTML from a web server.

My question is: how do I use hpple in my application? Should I use multiple URLs to import separated data and for every data object use `TFHpple` and `TFHppleElement` to manage the received data?